# JavaScript Arrays Numero mas grande

Tags: javascript

debo crear una funcion que reciba como parametros un array de numeros, y que retorne el numero mas grande en la posicion 0 y el mas pequeño en la posicion 1. Me ayudan?

Comment: Podrías añadir el código que has intentado hacer?

Comment: ufff ta dificil porque como esta la pandemia no deberia estar tan cerca te puedo dar la respuesta pero dandote cual es el numero mas grande en la posicion 0 y el numero mas chico enla posicion 3.. debemos seguir las normas,manteniendo una distanca adecuada asi evitamos contagio! juntos por un mejor planeta! de paso te dejo esta interesante nota de los creadores de stackoverflow llamada [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -2):

Dado que suena a un ejercicio de clase o algo similar, no te voy a dar la solución en código.

Pero la lógica sería: recorre la lista, guarda el primer número, compara el siguiente y guarda el más grande de ambos.

Comment: Te recomiendo no responder a preguntas mal planteadas pues terminan cerradas y tú aporte se perderá y corres el riesgo de negativos

Comment: @BetaM si.. estoy viendo un patrón que es votar negativo a respuestas correctas (pese a que la pregunta sea una basura..) por lo que supongo que voy a volverme a stackoverflow en inglés que allí al menos la gente parece tener mas sentido común al votar...

Comment: Yo te pido que nos sigas visitando todos los aportes son bienvenidos los votos negativos así no son cosa general (en algún momento por ejemplo yo también respondí a 1 o 2 preguntas de este estilo y me votaron negativo) pero en realidad en lo demás todo es excelente por aqui

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta. Para dejar comentarios usa el espacio de comentarios. Por otro lado, debemos evitar responder preguntas tan mal planteadas. Por favor leer [answer]. Saludos